# Sign SAAJ SOAPMessage with WS-Security

Tags: java, ws-security, saaj

Presently i am working on SOAP Service Automation in my product. SOAP Services are WS-Security enabled.

This is similar to SOAP UI tool where QE will test the services, we are using JAVA to achieve Automation.

i need to write a standalone client which takes the SOAP Message from a flat file (..\testdata\detailInquiry.xml) and dynamillcay add the input data from excel sheet.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cus:DetailInquiry>
         <request>
            <com:RequestUID>testdata1</com:RequestUID>
            <com:BaseServiceRqVersion>3</com:BaseServiceRqVersion>
            <ser:CustomerIdent>testdata2</ser:CustomerIdent>
            <ser:CustomerDetailInquiryRqVersion>1</ser:CustomerDetailInquiryRqVersion>
         </request>
      </cus:DetailInquiry>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Jars used : wss4j-1.6.9.jar , xmlsec-1.3.0.jar
Please find the Java code for reading the flat file and adding ws-security header in order to communicate to SOAP service.

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
            SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
            soapPart.setContent(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream("..\\testdata\\detailInquiry.xml")));
            Document  doc = toDocument(soapMessage); // Question doc is coming as null, why ?

              WSSecSignature builder = new WSSecSignature();
                WSSecTimestamp timestamp = new WSSecTimestamp();

                WSSecHeader wsSecHeader = new WSSecHeader();
                wsSecHeader.setMustUnderstand(true);
                wsSecHeader.insertSecurityHeader(doc);

               WSSecTimestamp wsSecTimeStamp = new WSSecTimestamp();
               wsSecTimeStamp.prepare(soapPart);
              // wsSecTimeStamp.prependToHeader(wsSecHeader);

               Properties cxfProps = new Properties();
                cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider", "org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
                cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type", "jks");
                cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias", CLIENT_KEYSTORE_ALIAS);
                cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", CLIENT_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD);
                cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file", CLIENT_KEYSTORE_PATH);

                Crypto crypto1 = CryptoFactory.getInstance(cxfProps);

                String bstId = builder.getBSTTokenId();
                builder.appendBSTElementToHeader(wsSecHeader);
                builder.setUserInfo(SIG_USERNAME, SIG_PASSWORD);
               // builder.setX509Certificate(cert);
                builder.setKeyIdentifierType(WSConstants.BST_DIRECT_REFERENCE);
                builder.setSignatureAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
                builder.setSigCanonicalization(WSConstants.C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
                builder.setDigestAlgo(WSConstants.SHA1);
                builder.setUseSingleCertificate(true);

                builder.build(soapPart, crypto1, wsSecHeader);

            soapMessage.saveChanges();

           soapMessage.writeTo(httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream());

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            soapMessage.writeTo(out);
            message = new String(out.toByteArray(),"UTF-8"); 
            StringBuffer xmlBuf = new StringBuffer(message);
            //    StringBuffer xmlBuf = new StringBuffer(soapMessage.writeTo());
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream()), xmlBuf.length());
            System.out.println("Request: \n" + xmlBuf.toString());
            writer.write(xmlBuf.toString());
            writer.close();
            System.out.println("Request Writer closed");
```

i am getting following exception :

```
16:48:32.490 [main] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig - The provider BC could not be added: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader.loadClass2(Loader.java:271)
    at org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:265)
    at org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:245)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.addJceProvider(WSSConfig.java:817)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig$4.run(WSSConfig.java:404)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig$4.run(WSSConfig.java:402)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:594)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.init(WSSConfig.java:401)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getNewInstance(WSSConfig.java:435)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecBase.getWsConfig(WSSecBase.java:118)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecTimestamp.prepare(WSSecTimestamp.java:72)
    at com.aci.sat.HTTPSSenderUpdatedSSL.sendRequest(HTTPSSenderUpdatedSSL.java:252)
    at com.aci.sat.HTTPSSenderUpdatedSSL.main(HTTPSSenderUpdatedSSL.java:119)
16:48:32.491 [main] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig - The provider STRTransform was added at position: 11
16:48:32.501 [main] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory - Using Crypto Engine [class org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin]
16:48:32.504 [main] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader - Trying to find [C:/Users/kthumu/Desktop/Saturn/SOATestProject_SoapUI/ClientKeyDev.jks] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c37ed64b class loader.
16:48:32.504 [main] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader - Trying to find [C:/Users/kthumu/Desktop/Saturn/SOATestProject_SoapUI/ClientKeyDev.jks] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c37ed64b class loader.
16:48:32.505 [main] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader - Trying to find [C:/Users/kthumu/Desktop/Saturn/SOATestProject_SoapUI/ClientKeyDev.jks] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
16:48:32.507 [main] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin - The KeyStore C:/Users/kthumu/Desktop/Saturn/SOATestProject_SoapUI/ClientKeyDev.jks of type jks has been loaded
16:48:32.507 [main] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature - Beginning signing...
Oct 03, 2018 4:48:32 PM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.SOAPPart1_2Impl createEnvelopeFromSource
SEVERE: SAAJ0415: InputStream does not represent a valid SOAP 1.2 Message
Exception sending request: General security error (No certificates for user SystemAdmin were found for signature)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: General security error (No certificates for user SystemAdmin were found for signature)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.getSigningCerts(WSSecSignature.java:790)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.prepare(WSSecSignature.java:168)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.build(WSSecSignature.java:362)
    at com.aci.sat.HTTPSSenderUpdatedSSL.sendRequest(HTTPSSenderUpdatedSSL.java:274)
    at com.aci.sat.HTTPSSenderUpdatedSSL.main(HTTPSSenderUpdatedSSL.java:119)
```

Can somebody ,please help me on what is the wrong i am doing.i am working on SAAJ,WS-Security for the first time. Please also suggest best way to achieve my requirement if i am in wrong direction.

please let me know if required any additional inputs to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following changes in code and right now SOAP request with ws security is being formed  :

```
Document  doc = soapMessage.getSOAPBody().getOwnerDocument();
              WSSecSignature builder = new WSSecSignature();
                WSSecTimestamp timestamp = new WSSecTimestamp();

                WSSecHeader wsSecHeader = new WSSecHeader();
                wsSecHeader.setMustUnderstand(true);
                wsSecHeader.insertSecurityHeader(doc);

               WSSecTimestamp wsSecTimeStamp = new WSSecTimestamp();
               wsSecTimeStamp.prepare(soapPart);
              // wsSecTimeStamp.prependToHeader(wsSecHeader);

               Properties cxfProps = new Properties();
                cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider", "org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
                cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type", "jks");
                cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias", CLIENT_KEYSTORE_ALIAS);
                cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", CLIENT_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD);
                cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file", CLIENT_KEYSTORE_PATH);

                Crypto crypto1 = CryptoFactory.getInstance(cxfProps);

                KeyStore ks2 = KeyStore.getInstance(keystoreType);
                InputStream fin = Util.getResourceInputStream(keystorepath);
                ks2.load(fin, keystorePwd.toCharArray());

                X509Certificate certificate = null;
              /*  Enumeration enumeration = ks2.aliases();

                while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                       String alias = (String)enumeration.nextElement();
                       System.out.println("alias--------------"+alias);
                       certificate = (X509Certificate) ks2.getCertificate(alias);
                       System.out.println("certificate------------"+certificate);
                   }*/

                certificate = (X509Certificate) ks2.getCertificate("soaclient");
                String bstId = builder.getBSTTokenId();
                builder.appendBSTElementToHeader(wsSecHeader);
                builder.setUserInfo("soaclient", "soaclient");
                builder.setX509Certificate(certificate);
                builder.setKeyIdentifierType(WSConstants.BST_DIRECT_REFERENCE);
                builder.setSignatureAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
                builder.setSigCanonicalization(WSConstants.C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
                builder.setDigestAlgo(WSConstants.SHA1);
                builder.setUseSingleCertificate(true);

                builder.build(soapPart, crypto1, wsSecHeader);

            soapMessage.saveChanges();

           soapMessage.writeTo(httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream());

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            soapMessage.writeTo(out);
            message = new String(out.toByteArray(),"UTF-8"); 

            StringBuffer xmlBuf = new StringBuffer(message);
```

SOAP Request throgh java code :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://aciworldwide.com/pim/common/components" xmlns:cus="http://aciworldwide.com/pim/messages/service/party/Customer" xmlns:ser="http://aciworldwide.com/pim/messages/party/customer/services">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-91AE8727984C6185B615385756472851">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-3"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="com cus ser soapenv"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><ds:Reference URI="#id-2"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="com cus ser"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>3Q65aPlsNuqnQTlpzNnFsFIzqCI=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>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</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-91AE8727984C6185B615385756472892"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-91AE8727984C6185B615385756472903"><wsse:Reference URI="#X509-91AE8727984C6185B615385756472851" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-2">
      <cus:DetailInquiry>
         <request>
            <com:RequestUID>c53a53a2-68da-4a11-a3b8-94e469e2237i</com:RequestUID>
            <com:BaseServiceRqVersion>3</com:BaseServiceRqVersion>
            <ser:CustomerIdent>CB10010</ser:CustomerIdent>
            <ser:CustomerDetailInquiryRqVersion>1</ser:CustomerDetailInquiryRqVersion>
         </request>
      </cus:DetailInquiry>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The Request that is sent through SOAPUI test is as follows :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:com="http://aciworldwide.com/pim/common/components" xmlns:cus="http://aciworldwide.com/pim/messages/service/party/Customer" xmlns:ser="http://aciworldwide.com/pim/messages/party/customer/services" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
[\n]"
 "   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EK-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465580637" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"/><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference><ds:X509Data><ds:X509IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName>CN=SOA Server,OU=Server,O=ACI WORLDWIDE INC,L=Norcross,ST=Georgia,C=US</ds:X509IssuerName><ds:X509SerialNumber>1477805662</ds:X509SerialNumber></ds:X509IssuerSerial></ds:X509Data></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData><xenc:ReferenceList><xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465580778"/><xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465581089"/><xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF153854655810810"/></xenc:ReferenceList></xenc:EncryptedKey><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465578683">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature Id="SIG-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465579196" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="com cus ser soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><ds:Reference URI="#TS-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465578482"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse com cus ser soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>mCK+EkmFnXvun5btsnyjx4XtXCc=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#UsernameToken-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465578461"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="com cus ser soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>qg4oHN0lcn3tuBEWjcdkerqt2dc=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>A5lz1AdPpP+n8m4bPzqfyn2cBuC4blJ3dWVBlOfq4+xU3qSQguYorGbvdkSFl02i6kbjaJQl56vU[\n]"
 "++imWaW2m0ddOBji0F/7A477n+I836wPDlYnshKRIXDDqJ0eOaGQtSjG+kAY9m7F7nA5MbL+3+YP[\n]"
 "trigoCpmezZwHiBrQ69FC1cKl9YSyhQkZ5PbhE39x84G1RR7myyCj8sXD9NC0lX1zS1ggARi9ff0[\n]"
 "BUicl5QB6Ws7GtNNYdQzK2Wyg+Ch1K/3BioGqGu2I/u2mWzTiBf87O6XIoCBUmLq6scAbX/JYIU7[\n]"
 "Y+/bqr6bzziBRCkPV9p0jiNeAqR81pQlcOY3qjSQkFRUZLSmMnS+5r2UDAiPWMm0pwA4OTrlYq1z[\n]"
 "4g74OG5Hy8Iqfhpu9jsrIH7s3IpyKKTHGWE1RK0UAS9mLKfBMAsrhpfqHORHkyRmIP1OSH5FZJba[\n]"
 "+Yeo7D0muevQWMawCiPABvDi3AMvXE3I3ZP0F7EjkswGqGNYJ0hATOXa</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465579084"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465579105"><wsse:Reference URI="#X509-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465578683" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465578482"><xenc:EncryptedData Id="ED-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465581089" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"><wsse:Reference URI="#EK-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465580637"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>TYdxgvz14yb5hxearLcPSihYdkNH2jgju18gZl79P2SKLMIUUJ3IfcPLfy1p0XZJIMC7R/3Y78miZbqQTq9nUNVlR6BTQ5MsunTmJZD0B6fFVsmRug3GFhSVvDJd2d/nfPit4XW1XyD0dDsrCZ4AqPvyNp64vWOXzwbXl3WYmGI=</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedData></wsu:Timestamp><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465578461"><xenc:EncryptedData Id="ED-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF153854655810810" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"><wsse:Reference URI="#EK-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465580637"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>5yFgPMluQweAKS529+iOdOPsTdH6fJAeN2YOS9J0ZFjc9GxJfFfsWmZbrM8IanuzPkYir9qCTLgnCzXQAMjl5zHygCPFF9f3qds+p78mxTfHPJObL0gpZl9qa7TOqW1U1wasyNhEUSd4YlW0edUi8nBUrsLbL5tOrT4mH2eUU2dgRZZjqk1yP1Cf1QuIDc3qFYx28CoSEbrmDGiY7zeDGwQ8/FEvj82yHdUHvUpVjBFYDu4MGhkH6StygpLhdrATdHDdrSxMJO3YmHbC6nVX7w==</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedData></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>


 [\n]"
 "   <soapenv:Body><xenc:EncryptedData Id="ED-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465580778" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"><wsse:Reference URI="#EK-761BF2BB9E9C5182BF15385465580637"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedData></soapenv:Body>[\n]"
 "</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can any body please suggest what additional changes i need to do to achieve the request like SOAPUI. At this moment through java code the SOAP Request is not reaching till server( i am not seeing any thing in Systemout or ep3 log which happens in cas of SOAPUI request)

Comment: hi did you find solution to this issue?